# when ever i click on expand icon in a cell , near by column's formatter call back function is triggering.. #tabulator

Tags: tabulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d72Pu.png)

in the above image , i have two columns , first one trade , second one contracts.the contracts column has expand and collapse option and the trade column has formatter call back function.when ever we click on the expand icon in contracts column , formatter call back function which is in trade column is triggered. formatter call back function should not be triggered...

I am expecting that formatter call back function not to be triggered...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.